# The inverse operation of tensor circular unfolding in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia, tensor

I implemented Tensor Circular Unfolding (TCU) defined in [this document](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9158539) (See Definition 2).
The TCU reshapes a tensor (or multidimensional array) `X` into a matrix (or two-dimensional array). By using `TensorToolbox`, I implemented that as follows:

```
using TensorToolbox
function TCU(X,d,k)
    N = ndims(X)
    @assert d < N
    if d <= k
        a = k-d+1
    else
        a = k-d+1+N
    end
    tenmat(permutedims(X,circshift(1:N,-a+1)),row=1:d)
end
```

for positive integers `d<N` and `k≦N` where `N` is the depth of input tensor `X`. The function `tenmat` comes from [TensorToolbox.jl](https://github.com/lanaperisa/TensorToolbox.jl) and it is for matricization of a tensor. Please see ReadMe file in [TensorToolbox.jl](https://github.com/lanaperisa/TensorToolbox.jl).

Here I put an example with `N=4`.

```
X = rand(1:9,3,4,2,2)
#3×4×2×2 Array{Int64, 4}:
#[:, :, 1, 1] =
# 5  7  2  6
# 4  5  6  2
# 6  8  9  1
#
#[:, :, 2, 1] =
# 4  3  7  5
# 8  3  3  1
# 8  2  4  7
#
#[:, :, 1, 2] =
# 4  3  9  6
# 7  4  9  2
# 6  7  2  4
#
#[:, :, 2, 2] =
# 9  2  1  7
# 8  2  1  3
# 6  2  4  9

M = TCU(X, 2, 3)
#8×6 Matrix{Int64}:
# 5  4  4  7  6  6
# 7  3  5  4  8  7
# 2  9  6  9  9  2
# 6  6  2  2  1  4
# 4  9  8  8  8  6
# 3  2  3  2  2  2
# 7  1  3  1  4  4
# 5  7  1  3  7  9
```

### What I need

I would like to write the reverse operation of the above function. That is, I need the function `InvTCU` that satisfies

```
X == InvTCU( TCU(X, d, k), d, k )
```

If we need, `InvTCU` can require the original tensor size `size(X)`

```
X == InvTCU( TCU(X, d, k), d, k, size(X) )
```

### The reason why I need `InvTCU`

It is required in Equation (18) in [the document](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9158539) to implement the algorithm named `PTRC`. In this situation, the size of the original tensor `size(X)` are available information.

#### EDIT

I added the description about `tenmat`.
I added the description that `InvTCU` can require the original tensor size.

Comment: The implementation of `tenmat` is important. If it returns a regular matrix array, there is a loss of information in the process. That is, a tensor of 2x2x3x3 could turn into a 4x9 matrix, and the reverse decomposition of rows and columns to smaller dimensions cannot be infered. **If** the returned object retains this information, then something can be done reasonably.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The function `tenmat` comes from TensorToolbox.jl and it is for matricization of a tensor. I could not find official documentation for this function but we can refer to the description in Readme file in TensorToolbox.jl  https://github.com/lanaperisa/TensorToolbox.jl

Comment: @DanGetz Sorry, I did not notice your modifying comment. `tenmat` returns a regular matrix. I agree the function reduces information, which is why I assume the function `InvTCU` requires `k` and `d`.

Comment: But, in fact, it reduces information more than `k`, `d` can recover... if there was some constraint on the sizes of dimensions in the original tensor, then this would be easier (i.e. original NxNxNxN tensor).

Comment: @DanGetz Oh, I did not consider this point... The input tensor size should be arbitrary. I think `InvTCU` need to require the original tensor size; that is we should find the function `InvTCU` that satisfies `X == InvTCU( TCU(X, d, k), d, k, size(X) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before giving the function, it might be noted that to get the matrixfied tensor, it is possible to use views instead of permuting the dimensions, which might be more efficient (depending on processing later). This can be done (I think) with the TrasmuteDims or TensorCast packages (https://docs.juliahub.com/TransmuteDims/NIYrh/0.1.15/).

Here is an attempt at a `permutedims` approach:

```
function invTCU(M,d,k, presize)
    N = length(presize)
    a = d<=k ? k-d+1 : k-d+1+N
    X = reshape(M,Tuple(circshift(collect(presize),1-a)))
    permutedims(X,circshift(1:N,a-1))
end
```

with this definition:

```
julia> X = reshape(1:48,3,4,2,2)
3×4×2×2 reshape(::UnitRange{Int64}, 3, 4, 2, 2) with eltype Int64:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
 1  4  7  10
...

julia> X == invTCU(TCU(X, 2, 3), 2, 3, size(X))
true
```

seems to recover original tensor.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I should probably use these packages instead of `permutedims` in `invTCU` and `TCU`. But I am confused about the differences between the default function `PermutedDimsArray` and your listed packages. In these usages, I guess `PermutedDimsArray` is enough, isn't it?

Comment: Checking the docs, I think PermutedDimsArray does the permuting dims bit. TensorCast can also do the `tenmat` operation (and these packages support various speed optimizations and worth a look in general).

Comment: I found some descriptions in ReadMe in TransmuteDims. What I need seems to be `transmute`. It seems much faster than `permutedims`. I mean, I should replace `permutedims(X, (a,b,c))` with `transmute(X, (a,b,c))`. I appreciate your valuable advice.

Comment: P.S. In your proposed `invTCU`, I think the definition of `N` need to be the first line.